# merge two fasta files in python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to merge two fasta files. I tried: copy file1.fasta+file2.fasta > bit_fasta.fasta
However, it only wrote the last file in the bit_fasta. 
So now, I'm writing a scrip in python to concatenate this fasta files:
So I created a dictionary for each of file and then merged those dictionaries into one large dictionary:

```
out_file=open('outfile.fasta','w')
new_dictionary={}
for keys_1,values_1 in 1_dictionary.items():
    new_dictionary[keys_1]=[values_1 ]
    for keys_2,values_2 in 2_dictionary.items():
        new_dictionary[keys_2]=[values_2 ]
        for new_key,new_value in new_dictionary.items():
            out_file.write(str(new_key)+'\n'+str(new_value[0])+'\n')
```

However it generated a larger file. Can someone point me to the write direction?

Input:

```
1_dictionary={'>ID1':AHSNDBF,'>ID2':ACTGTATC,'>ID3':ACTTTG}
2_dictionary={'>ID':ACTGT,'>ID1.1':ACCTGT,'>ID2.1':ATTTG}
```

Expected output:

```
new_dictionary={'>ID1':AHSNDBF,'>ID2':ACTGTATC,'>ID3':ACTTTG,'>ID':ACTGT,'>ID1.1':ACCTGT,'>ID2.1':ATTTG}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and put there sample (small) input and expected output?

Comment: I edited my question to have a small input and output

Answer (score 0):

To create new dictionary from the two, you can use for example:

```
dictionary_1 ={'>ID1':'AHSNDBF','>ID2':'ACTGTATC','>ID3':'ACTTTG'}
dictionary_2 ={'>ID':'ACTGT','>ID1.1':'ACCTGT','>ID2.1':'ATTTG'}

new_dictionary = dict(**dictionary_1, **dictionary_2)
print(new_dictionary)
```

Prints:

```
{'>ID1': 'AHSNDBF', '>ID2': 'ACTGTATC', '>ID3': 'ACTTTG', '>ID': 'ACTGT', '>ID1.1': 'ACCTGT', '>ID2.1': 'ATTTG'}
```